# cocos2d v3 re-orient screen during App use

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, orientation

So in cocos2d (I believe I was on v2.1) I did this to lock and set the orientations:

```
        AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    const UIInterfaceOrientation ORIENTATION = delegate.navController.interfaceOrientation;
    delegate.navController.
    delegate.navController.screenOrientation = ORIENTATION == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    UIViewController *mVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [delegate.navController presentModalViewController:mVC animated:NO];
    [delegate.navController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

With some functions added to the AppDelegate.
I cannot seem to get the same results in iOS7 and cocos2d v3.

I have dug through a bit and the proper functions seem to be in place but cannot seem to set up a global variable to set the orientation and return only the one I want at the certain time.  Can someone point me down the proper path.  I think I'm missing something really small cause the proper code seems to be there already.

Here's the code for my AppDelegate

```
@implementation AppDelegate

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self setupCocos2dWithOptions:@{
        CCSetupShowDebugStats: @(NO),
    }];

[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

return YES;

}

-(CCScene *)startScene
{
    return [HomeScreen scene];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

My code never hits the interfaceOrientation functions.

Thoughts??!?

Comment: did you implement/modify the view controller's supportedInterfaceOrientations method?

Comment: I have not- as I see it in CCAppDelegate.  When I do bring it into my AppDelegate though I cannot access the _screenOrientation variable.... Also when I implement supportedInterfaceOrientations method I don't see my trace output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple days fooling around I figured out a solution:

in AppDelegate I needed this function:

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if (!self.lockedToOrientation) {
        if( [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ){
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
        }

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
    else {
        return self.lockedToOrientation;
    }
}
```

Where

```
@property UIInterfaceOrientationMask lockedToOrientation;
```

Hope this helps someone!

Cheers.