# cocos2d-x force orientation change within a scene

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am making an iOS game in cocos2d-x v3.I want to set different orientations for different scenes.For example,Scene1 should be portrait and scene2 should be landscape.I don't want users to tilt the device again and again.How can I achieve that? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22353111/cocos2d-v3-re-orient-screen-during-app-use ?